# build mobile version for subset of website pages?

Tags: android, iphone, mobile, asp-classic, mobile-phones

I have an asp website which contains several pages related to a wizard. I was wondering if it was possible to create a mobile version for the wizard pages only. Hence, when I open my website on a mobile device, it would open up as normal, but if I navigate to the wizard pages, these would open up in the mobile version.

How easy/difficult would it be to accomplish that? This is my 1st attempt at building mobile pages so any info on how to approach this would be greatly appreciated. building
Thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

Here you go:

http://coding.smashingmagazine.com/2010/07/19/how-to-use-css3-media-queries-to-create-a-mobile-version-of-your-website/